# How to rewrite a deeply nested block?

Tags: blocks, overrides

So I'm writing a module that would rewrite this class: Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes_Special.

It rewrites the getElementHtml() method.

My question is, how do I reference this in my modules main etc/config.xml? I would normally think it would be done like this:

```
<config>
    <global>
      <blocks>
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes>MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
      </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Is that config.xml done correctly? If not, how should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close.

```
<config>
    <global>
      <blocks>
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes_special>MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes_special>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
      </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

**We can rewrite a "deeply" nested block as like a "leastly" nested block. :)**

Suppose the method that you need to rewrite a block `Namespace_Modulename_Block_Nest1_Nest2_Nest3_Nest4_Nest5`, then your rewrite should look like

```
<config>
    <global>
      <blocks>
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <nest1_nest2_nest3_nest4_nest5>MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Block_Namespace_Mynest1_Mynest2_Mynest3_Mynest4_Mynest5</nest1_nest2_nest3_nest4_nest5>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
      </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

and your block definition should look like this

Location : `app/code/local/MyNamespace/MyModuleName/Block/Namespace/Mynest1/Mynest2/Mynest3/Mynest4/Mynest5.php`

```
<?php
class MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Block_Namespace_Mynest1_Mynest2_Mynest3_Mynest4_Mynest5 
    extends Namespace_Modulename_Block_Nest1_Nest2_Nest3_Nest4_Nest5
{
   //rewriting method comes here.
}
```

You can rewrite the block anywhere in you Module's block scope. It is not a strict rule your block definition should look like `MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Block_Namespace_Mynest1_Mynest2_Mynest3_Mynest4_Mynest5`. Your rewrite may be `MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Block_Namespace_Mynest5`. For that case, the location your file resides and hence the classname changes accordingly.

Hope it gives some general idea

Comment: Actually I found that in the <rewrite> element you don't do <namespace_nest1_nest2_etc> you just do <nest1_nest2_etc> and also by convention Namespace comes before Block in the actual value like: MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Namespace_Block_Nest1_Nest2_etc. (though it doesn't really matter because you can technically call it whatever you want I think, it just comes down to convention).

Comment: @CommaToast: Thanks for pointing out the error. I edited my answer. I am normally use `Mynamespace_Mymodulename_Block_Namespce_etc` to define my rewrite block. As I already mentioned at last part of my answer, its not at all a strict rule. Thanks again for your time. :)